# Remove JS file from mobile memory

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery-mobile

I had developing a mobile project with JQM 1.2.0 and Jquery 1.8.2 with different modules. 
For mobile performance i will dynamically loading javascript files based on each module.
Reference link: [Javascript Kit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml)

The problem is, in the case of JavaScript, the file is removed from the document tree, but the code of the external JavaScript file remains in the browser's memory.

How we remove or clear that mobile's browser memory?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `delete` on some vars that are in global scope.
But generally this should not be necessary, as the browser has a gc when no reference are pointing to a resource.

so clear any resource to something, and it will get removed. just be sure, you put your reference at one place, where you can remove them later

```
//create something in the global scope
window.myNamespace = {};

myNamespace["oneClass"] = function() {};

// and then

delete window.myNamespace;
```

Comment: Hi Luke, Thank you for your reply. I used the above code still i can able to access a method inside that removed js file.

Comment: thats not possible, tell me `how` you access it. then think about, where you use it. so if you purely say something like `executeFunction()` without a namespace, it means that the function is in the global scope. therefore you nede to use `delete window.executeFunction` ...

Comment: For example: 'File A' has 2 buttons one is 'loadJs' another one is 'RemoveJs'.  When click on LoadJs... 'newJS.js' file has been added in 'File A' which has 'executeFunction()'. I will remove that js file by clicking that 'RemoveJs' button. After that still i can able to access 'executeFunction()'.

Comment: yes of course. a file is only something to read from. after it is read, the file can be deleted and the stuff is still there. therefore you **have to** `delete` explicitly any reference, if you dont want to have it be there. you have to do it manually!!! using `delete window.executeFunction` and all other variables that are populated when executing a js file